# How to append a string before pattern while keeping the string as it is?

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I tried to do this with finding location of pattern but while replacing, i am unable to keep old string. following is example:

```
old <- "(101==1,2) AND (102==1)"
str_replace_all(old, "\\(\\d+", replacement = "(stringToReplace")
```

This is printing

```
(stringToReplace==1,2) AND (stringToReplace==1)
```

But I want output as

```
(stringToReplace101==1,2) AND (stringToReplace102==1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place brackets around parts of your regular expression. You can reference these using `\1`, `\2` etc. In this case I added brackets around the `\\d+`, with the `\\1` in the replacement I add everything that was matched with the first set of brackets:

```
str_replace_all(old, "\\((\\d+)", replacement = "(stringToReplace\\1")
```

For more info see for example the section *Replacing Regex Matches in String Vectors* in [Regular Expressions with The R Language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)